# Obtaining driving length between stops in ArcGIS

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

How can I obtain driving length between two stops in ArcGIS? I'm placing route from RouteTask service on a map and want to get lengths from that response too. I've thought about doing some iteration in DirectionsFeatureSet, but I already see that what I'm doing is complete nonsense.

```
        var directions = solveResult[0].directions;
        console.log(directions);
        var length = 0;
        var location = 0;
        var obj = {};
        $.each(directions.features, function (ind, val) {
            var txt = val.attributes.text;
            var indexOfLocation = txt.indexOf('Location');
            if (indexOfLocation != -1) {
                var digitTransform = txt.substring(indexOfLocation + 9);
                var digit = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < digitTransform.length; i++) {
                    var char = digitTransform[i];
                    if (isNumber(char)) {
                        digit += char;
                    } else break;
                }

            }
        });
```

That's what I already did and that makes no sense.

In Google Maps API it's clear - every leg has it's own length. In ArcGIS responses I see no such easy approach.

Answer (score 1):

The length is available as an attribute of each returned feature.  So, given your directions variable, the following would give you the length of the first leg of the route:

`directions.features[0].attributes.length`